# Why am I not seeing my stderr println after my stdout println?

Tags: java, stdout, output, stderr, println

```
   public static void algorithmOne(int n){

      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      search:
      for (int possiblePrime = 2; possiblePrime <= n; possiblePrime++){

         for (int divisor = 2; divisor < possiblePrime; divisor++)
            if ( possiblePrime%divisor == 0 && possiblePrime != divisor )
               continue search;

         System.out.println(possiblePrime);
      }
      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.err.println(endTime - startTime);
   }
```

This is a method to find prime numbers I cant work out why i don't reach the "System.err.println(endTime - startTime);" line.

Comment: An integer I have to find all the primes from 2 to N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you **are** reaching your time difference println(), but you're not seeing it where you expect. This is because you're printing it to stderr - so you're not guaranteed it gets appended after all of the println()'s to standard output.

Try printing to stdout instead...

As for your algorithm for primality testing  - have a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385909/most-elegant-way-to-write-isprime-in-java) two [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2924452/1593077) about deciding primality (there are links there). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23287/1593077) discusses finding prime factors, which is not the same problem but has some insights you might be interested in. Specifically, consider the following:

- Your inner loop only needs to go up to `sqrt(n)`, as if a is a factor of n, then so is n/a.
- All prime factors after 3 are of the form 6n-1 or 6n+1 (think about it), so you can loop over . If you think of the [Sieve of Erathostenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) you can think of additional such 'dirty' optimizations.

That's "easy stuff", there's a lot more you could do. But, really, why should you even write a primality test yourself? There is [existing code](http://www2-fs.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/~reinhard/krypto/AKSTest/AKSeng.html) you could use.

Comment: eek :( I posted algorithm one instead of number two which was the one that had the problem.
but any how I had System.out.err(endTime - startTime); instead of System.err.println(endTime - startTime) 
The program still compiled so ive been having issues with another issue that wass all cause by this...

Comment: @bob: I still recommend that you read up a bit on primality testing, it's quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    search: for (int possiblePrime = 2; possiblePrime <= 10; possiblePrime++) {

        for (int divisor = 2; divisor < possiblePrime; divisor++)
            if (possiblePrime % divisor == 0 && possiblePrime != divisor)
                continue search;

        System.out.println(possiblePrime);
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(startTime);
    System.out.println(endTime);
    System.out.println("Total time taken is : " + (endTime - startTime));
```